# My code for running category-specific loop does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a code to run a loop to get three posts of a specific category. Now when I run this code, it works in place, but another loop fails to work properly. The destroyed loop is a loop which simply fetches content for single.php.

In other words, the below code (which is for category-specific loop) only causes another script in the single.php page to fail. But it works for all other pages. what is the cause of this issue? thanks very much

```
    query_posts('in_category=پیشنهاد&posts_per_page=3');

    if( have_posts() ) : while(have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li>     
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <div class='entry-suggested-title'>
             <p><?php the_title();?></p>                            
        </div>                       
        <div class='entry-suggested-image'>
           <?php
            the_post_thumbnail(array(182,182), array('alt'=>get_the_title()));
        the_title();
           ?>
         </div>     
       </a>                   
    </li>       
   <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;      
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: uery_posts() does not exist please correct your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class instead of [`query_posts();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) ( [Why?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) ).
There is no `in_category` parameter, it should be `category__in`.

```
$args = array(
  'category__in' => array( 4 ),
  'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  the_title()
  the_permalink();
endwhile; endif;
```

`in_category();` is a [`Conditional Tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and it should be used in the Loop:

```
if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  if( in_category( '4' ){
    //Do something with the post that belong to category ID 4
  }else{
    //Do something else
  }
endwhile; endif;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks very much. exactly what I needed. I also added get_cat_id to retrieve id of the cat.